# Unique home page visit animation. Possible?

Tags: animation, indexing, slider, unique

When a link is clicked the entire wrapper slides away and the proceeding page appears to slide into place.  I want this to happen when the home page is clicked from another page, but I want a different animation depending on where in my site the user came from.  I don't want an animation when the user comes to my page from an external source. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is def possible.

You can use javascript/ajax for navigating around your site.

For example, you can have two or more(if you need) content containers inside your wrapper. When the user clicks a link, you can either load the content into a container out of view or just have containers already with content (depends on your site's needs), and then animate it in however you want.

To know where your user is coming from, either change the url through history api (check out history.js) as it is generally good to have unique url for the different contents of a site, or just save the current location in a variable. Then you can either parse the url or check the value of the location variable before animating in the new content. You should of course push the new url or save the new location to the location variable after.

When a user comes from an external source, just load the page as normal without javascript animation.

Very simple examples:

```
    $("#home-btn").on('click', function(){
        //check where user's coming from, 
        //animate and show home content,
        //push, save current location
    });
```

or

```
   $(".all-btns").on('click', function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      //check where user's coming from,

      if($this.attr('id') == 'home-btn'){
          //animate and show home content
      } else {
          //animate and show other content
      }

      //push, save current location
   });
```

I'm sure you can figure the rest out.